# Target dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('.class-name').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

So it targets `.class-name` and works fine on page load.

I want it to also target any elements **that is added dynamically** (after page load) with class `.class-name`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Put that code in a function, then call it again after you add the new dynamic content - or better yet, include the prepended data in what you actually add to the DOM in the first place

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The dynamically added elements are added by a third-party function and happens quite randomly.

Comment: That is information that's vital to your situation which should really be in the question. Does the third party function expose any events when content is added? If so you should call `prepend()` within that event. If not, look in to using MutationObservers, although note that they are not fully supported in all browsers.

Comment: @NenadVracar there's no click event handler in the OPs code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Any way I can find out if the third-party function is exposing any events without looking into the (very messy) code?

Comment: I'd hope they have some documentation online somewhere you can refer to

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is there no way to track/listen into the events and find it out that way?

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` handler to dynamically target newly added elements on the page.

```js
$('document').on('event', '.class-name' function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see an event handler in the OPs code?

Comment: I would assume OP had to do code wrapping in some sort of event.